# Windows Forms On Clicking on text in a TextBox in a FlowLayoutPanel the text moves and is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, flowlayoutpanel

1. Create A FlowLayoutPanel with a height of 50px and a width of 50 px, set autoscroll to true.
2. Insert a textbox into the FlowLayoutPanel set the textbox Multilineto true, Set the height to 200.
3. Paste a page of text into the text field of the textbox.
4. Run your program and click on the text in the textbox. You should see the text move and possible one line of text will automatically be selected.

Why does this happen? Any way to stop this behavior?

Comment: What exact behaviour you want?

Comment: I would expect the text not to move.